# Отследить превышение значения у UpDown

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется NumericUpDown, у которого выставлено максимальное значение:

```
        this.DimCountUpDown.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
        10000,
        0,
        0,
        0});
```

Мне необходимо отследить, когда пользователь введет с клавиатуры больше 10000 тысяч и выдать ему соответствующее уведомление. Пробую делать так:

```
    private void DimCountUpDown_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DimCountUpDown.Value > 10000)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Значение не должно превышать 10000", "Ошибка ввода");
            DimCountUpDown.Value = 10000;
        }
    }
```

Однако, перед тем как попасть сюда введенное значение (например, 10001) уже автоматически устанавливается на максимум (10000) и соответственно условие не срабатывает...

Comment: Ну так не выставляйте максимальное значение

Comment: @VladD, это как? Maximum должен содержать какое-то значение.

Comment: А если убрать строчку `this.DimCountUpDown.Maximum = ...` вообще?

Comment: @VladD, если её убрать, то в Свойствах для данного контрола устанавливается значение по умолчанию - 100.

Comment: Окей, попробуйте `this.DimCountUpDown.Maximum = decimal.MaxValue;` Ну или например значение 10001 по идее должно хватить.

Comment: decimal.MaxValue - то, что надо. Благодарю Вас!

Comment: @VladD преобразуйте ответ в комментарий.

Comment: @andreycha, лучше наоборот :)

Comment: Готово, добавил ответ.

Comment: @UnityMan это я местами перепутал ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По идее, у вас проверка происходит в `DimCountUpDown_KeyUp`, так что вам нужно отключить действие максимума. Для этого достаточно поставить в `Maximum` большее чем 10000 значение, например, 10001. Или чтобы не думать, можно просто поставить максимально возможное:

```
this.DimCountUpDown.Maximum = decimal.MaxValue;
```

Comment: Кстати, в Form1.Designer.cs строка <!-- language: c# --> this.DimCountUpDown.Maximum = decimal.MaxValue; преобразовалась в<!-- language: c# --> this.DimCountUpDown.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
            -1,
            -1,
            -1,
            0});
Блин, в комментах блок кода никак не оформить?

Comment: @UnityMan: Судя по всему, это одно и то же. В [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) описан точный смысл этих байт.

Comment: @UnityMan используйте ``: `код`

Answer (score 1):

> DimCountUpDown_KeyUp

Подключите обработчик к событию KeyDown.

UPDATE:

NumericUpDown это контейнер для контролов: UpDownButtons и UpDownEdit.
Несмотря на то, что они непубличные, но базовый класс - Control.
Если надо выводить сообщение при нажатии updown, то можно подключить обработчик к событию Click.

```
var max = 10000;

// обработчик нажатия кнопки updown
void UpDownButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var c = (sender as Control).Parent as NumericUpDown;
    // выводим сообщение 
    if (c.Value == max) {
        MessageBox.Show("Значение не должно превышать " + max, 
                          "Ошибка ввода");
    }
}

var f = new Form();
var c = new NumericUpDown() { Parent = f, Maximum = max, Value = 9999 };
// подключаем обработчик к updown
foreach (var b in c.Controls.OfType<Control>())
    b.Click += UpDownButton_Click;
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Это не вариант, т.к. там в DimCountUpDown.Value будет находиться предыдущее значение.

Comment: понятно. я обновил ответ.